# Split large INSERT query into smaller pieces

Tags: mysql

I have a very large INSERT-query which combines data from multiple tables into a new one.

This query runs on tables with hundred-thousands of rows, so it takes very long when executing it.

Is there a way to break it into smaller pieces, so it takes the first 200 usernames of the table which is used for the join `HypeAuditor - h.username` first and then make the insert, take the next batch of 200 usernames and so on?

Here is the code:

```
INSERT INTO Kombiniert
(username, fullname, followers_heepsy, followers_ninjaoutreach, followers_average, engagement_heepsy, engagement_ninjaoutreach, engagement_hypeauditor, engagement_average, city, state, country, category1, category2, category3, category4, category5, category6, follower_interest1, follower_interest1_share, follower_interest2, follower_interest2_share, follower_interest3, follower_interest3_share, follower_country, follower_country_share, follower_country_total, follower_country_engaged)
    Select bb.*, follower_country_total*engagement_average as follower_country_engaged from
        (
            Select aa.*, followers_average*follower_country_share as follower_country_total from 
            (
                select 
                h.username,
                nj.fullname,
                hy.followers as followers_heepsy,
                nj.followers as followers_ninjaoutreach,
                case when hy.followers IS NULL AND nj.followers>0 THEN nj.followers
                when hy.followers>0 AND nj.followers IS NULL THEN hy.followers
                else (hy.followers+nj.followers)/2 end as followers_average,
                hy.engagement/100 as engagement_heepsy,
                nj.engagement/100 as engagement_ninjaoutreach,
                h.engagement/100 as engagement_hypeauditor,
                case    when hy.engagement IS NULL AND nj.engagement IS NULL AND h.engagement>0 THEN h.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement IS NULL AND nj.engagement>0 AND h.engagement IS NULL THEN nj.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement>0 AND nj.engagement IS NULL AND h.engagement IS NULL THEN hy.engagement/100
                        when hy.engagement IS NULL AND nj.engagement>0 AND h.engagement>0 THEN (h.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        when hy.engagement>0 AND nj.engagement>0 AND h.engagement IS NULL THEN (hy.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100)/2
                        when hy.engagement>0 AND nj.engagement IS NULL AND h.engagement>0 THEN (h.engagement/100+hy.engagement/100)/2
                        else (hy.engagement/100+nj.engagement/100+h.engagement/100)/3 end as engagement_average,
                nj.city,
                nj.state,
                nj.country ,
                nj.category_1,
                nj.category_2,
                nj.category_3,
                nj.category_4,
                nj.category_5,
                nj.category_6,
                h.interest1,
                h.Interest1_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share1,
                h.interest2,
                h.Interest2_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share2,
                h.interest3,
                h.Interest3_percentage/100 as follower_interest_share3,
                h.country as follower_country,
                h.country_percentage/100 as follower_country_share


                from HypeAuditor h
                left join Heepsy hy on h.username = hy.username
                left join NinjaOutreach nj on nj.username=h.username
                ) aa 
            ) bb
```

Comment: I don't see the point of the subqueries.  If you remove them, maybe the insert would perform well enough already.